# The server is taking too long to respond

Tags: php

I have the PHP & MySQL, Linux website is running internet and people are accessing it. Often I get like this comment from some users which has displayed browser,

"The connection has timed out
The server at testsite.in http://testsite.in/ is taking too long to respond."

What could be the problem ? Do I need to work on the coding or server ? I feel that coding is OK which very simple straight forward coding written.

Comment: *"very simple straight forward code"* is rather subjective. `while (true)` is simple and straight forward but will exhibit the symptoms you describe... :-P Some more detail is needed.

Comment: No information supplied. Could be many reasons.

Comment: Uh, yeah, a lot more detail is needed. It's just a website with links to a number of apps and bobs. Which of them cause trouble? Surely not the front-page? Are they all PHP? (I spotted several Flash sites) What's its purpose?

Comment: It is a portal and has lot of features to serve.

Comment: "It is a portal and has lot of features to serve." - I laughed so hard, I fear I may have burst something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting timeouts on the main page, and that seems to just be an index.  Clearly either the server itself or your bandwidth is bogging down.

Running the 'top' command on the unix command line should tell you whether any processes are taking a lot of resources - use that as a start to determine whether your server is bogging down and why.

Comment: I'm sorry, this http://testsite.in/ .. not mine. i just mentioned instead of my real domain..

Comment: @log And that's why you use [`example.com`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com). :)